# Appending unique values only in a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, append

```
typedef struct child {int count; char word[100]; inner_list*next;} child;
typedef struct parent
{ char data [100];
child * head;
int count;
parent * next; } parent;

void append(child **q,char num[100],int size)
{   child *temp,*r,*temp2,*temp3;
parent *out=NULL;
  temp = *q;
  temp2 = *q;
  temp3 = *q;
  char *str;
  if(*q==NULL)
  {   temp = (child *)malloc(sizeof(child));
    strcpy(temp->word,num);
    temp->count =size;
    temp->next=NULL;
    *q=temp;
  }
  else
  {  temp = *q;
   while(temp->next !=NULL)
   {  temp=temp->next;
   }
   r = (child *)malloc(sizeof(child));
   strcpy(r->word,num);
   r->count = size;
   r->next=NULL;
   temp->next=r;
  }

}
```

This is my append function which I use for adding an element to my child list. But my problem is it only should append unique values which are followed by a string. Which means :

```
Inputs :  aaa bbb aaa ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa
```

Append should act :

```
For aaa string there  should be a list like bbb->ccc(Not bbb->ccc->bbb since bbb is already there if bbb is coming more than one time it should be increase count only.)
For bbb string there should be list like aaa->ccc only
For ccc string there should be list like aaa only
```

I hope i could make myself clear. Is there any ideas? Please ask for further info.

What i've tried is checking the previous elements entered with the new element. I kinda failed it.

```
int search(child *p)
{
    child *temp= (child *)malloc(sizeof(child));
    int var =0;
char num[100];
temp = p;
strcpy(num,p->word);
while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {

    if(strcmp(temp->word,num)==0)
    var =1;
    temp=temp->next;
    }
return var;
}
```

This is what i've tried so far. With this search function i would control if the element is here or not. But it failed.

Comment: This is not a supermarket for free code, this is a question and answer site. Try to solve the problem yourself, and come back when you find a *specific* problem you tried to solve and failed.

Comment: AS you can see i'm asking an IDEA not a free code. And it is a specific problem.

Comment: Where is your definition of `inner_list`?  And the code that adds things to the parent?  In fact, all you are doing in that method is allocating a new node and optionally appending it to an existing `inner_list`, with nothing to suggest even part of the behavior you're asking for.  Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: In that case, @LuckySlevin, the idea would be to look in the list, and if the new value is there, don't add it.

Comment: @Blair i will add what i tried in a short moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, given the inputs

```
aaa bbb aaa ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa
```

You want the parent list to have 3 elements - a child list for `aaa`, one for `bbb` and one for `ccc`.

The list for `aaa` should contain all strings that followed `aaa` in the original input, which here is just `bbb` and `ccc`.  It should only contain them once each, with the `count` variable in the corresponding nodes incremented so that `bbb`'s count is 2 and `ccc`'s count is 1.

Is this correct?  If it is, read on.

```
for every string S in your input
{
   if S is not associated with a child list in the parent
   {
      create a new child list associated with S at the end of the parent list
   }

   // now we have C, the child list we either found above or created
   if there is a string S' after S
   {
      find the element S' in the child list C by iterating through it
      if you don't find the element S', create/append it with count = 1
      else when you find the element, increment its count
   }
}
```

I think this should get you where you want to go.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Another pointer - use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` in your code, to protect against overflow.

Comment: I also thank you for not judging and helping me out by giving the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another conditional to your while loop:

```
while(temp->next !=NULL)
```

Basically just extend it to compare the value at the current iteration with your input value. If the two are equal then just return from `append`.