# Remove duplicates in a linked list before adding - C

Tags: c, search

My question is about removing duplicates from a linked list. But i want to do it before adding to linked list.

```
struct myStr{int number; mystr *next;}
void append(mystr **q,int item)
{
myStr *temp;
temp = *q;
myStr *newone;
if(*q==NULL)// There should be control of previous elements. Call of keysearch function.
     {   temp = (myStr *)malloc(sizeof(myStr));

          temp->number =size;
          temp->next=NULL;
          *q=temp;
     }
     else //And also here
     {  temp = *q;
         while(temp->next !=NULL)
         {  temp=temp->next;
         }
         newone = (myStr *)malloc(sizeof(myStr));
         newone->count = size;
         newone->next=NULL;
         temp->next=newone;

     }
}
int keysearch (myStr *p)
{
struct myStr *temp = p;
int found = 0;
int key= p->number;
while (temp->next != NULL) 
 {
 if(temp->number == key)
    {
   return 1;
//break;
        }
     temp = temp->next;   
     }
    return 0;
    }
```

My problem is in keySearch. I don't know what is wrong? Or is there another way for doing this.

Comment: Are you @LuckySlevin?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840228 has code that looks very similar to this in style and naming conventions.

Comment: This looks suspiciously similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840228/appending-unique-values-only-in-a-linked-list-in-c - The code is almost exactly the same. Nice try on changing the variable names.

Comment: @Phil I think its just several people working on the same assignment, we were bound to see that eventually. @DesperateCoders - please tag this as homework if it is homework.

Comment: I don't know. I got this code from a website and make some arrangements on it. Also, a code can not be unique i guess :S.

Comment: @Tim Post: It's exactly the same code, except with the variable names changed. This is not a coincidence.

Comment: @Tim, good call on that!

Comment: @interjay there are bunch of similar codes on the internet.

Comment: @DesperateCoders - is this a homework assignment?  Can you look at the linked question to see if you reocgnize it?  If that guy's question is the same or similar to yours, then I think I know what you need to do (in pseudo-code)

Comment: @Phil It is a semi-project i can say. I saw the guy's question. It is kinda same but not wholely. I need the action in the append function. where will i call it and how? Also, that guy seems to have the answer for his question already. I don't understand the accusations :S.

Comment: @interjay - The code looks different enough to be several students in the same class working under the same set of instructions, while following the same 'tutorial' found somewhere on the web. I don't think we're dealing with the same person here, but I am quite convinced that this is homework.

Comment: @Tim I already said it is a semi-project.

Comment: @DesperateCoders, I answered below with what I think is the correct implementation of the method.  I'm comfortable giving it to you because the meat of the `append` method is still up to you to write.

Comment: Never mind I misread the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have 2 comments where you expect to be invoking `keySearch`.  In fact, you only need it in 1 place - the second comment.  This is because the first place is where you are creating a brand new list, so of course nothing will be in it that you need to worry about.

In the second case, you want to call this `keySearch` method.  There are 3 types of `keySearch` methods I can think of that would be useful:

1. Invoke a method `int keySearch(mystr *p, int value)` that looks through `p` for `value` and, if found, returns `true` (non-zero number)
2. Invoke a method `int keySearch(mystr *p)` that looks through `p` for any duplicates and removes them.  This would not be called on every append, though, and the implementation above suggests this is not what you are trying to do.  It's a lot more work to do this, in any event.
3. Invoke a method `int keySearch(mystr *p)` that looks through `p` to see if the first value in `q` is duplicated, returning `true` if it is.  It seems this is what your method is trying to do.

Based on the signature of the method, you are trying to do #2 or #3.  But both of those are wrong-headed - they assume you've already added the duplicate to the list.  What you should be doing instead is trying to prevent a duplicate from being added in the first place.  The method as it is does not have enough information to do that, though.  It needs the value of the element that has not yet been added.

I would suggest changing the method to the one in #1, and passing in the value you **want** to add.  If it is found, return 1.  In the `append` method, if this function evaluates to 1, don't append anything.  Otherwise append the new element.

```
int keysearch(struct myStr *p, int value)
{
   if(p == NULL) return 0;
   // reusing p is fine - it's a local variable
   while(p != NULL)
   {
      if(p->number == value) return 1;  // return if value exists already
      p = p->next;                      // go to next element
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Now, when you are about to add an element, first run it by this method.  If the method returns 1, leave your `append` method immediately - there is nothing to be done.  If it returns 0, then `malloc` your new node and set it to the end of the list.

---

**EDIT**: An enterprising codesmith may want to optimize slightly so that on every `append` we don't do 2 loops through the whole list (one for `keySearch`, and then one to find the last element for actual appending).  You can do this by modifying `keySearch` slightly...

```
// returns NULL if p is empty / value exists; otherwise returns the last element
struct myStr *keysearch(struct myStr *p, int value)
{
   // same logic, different return values; integration into append changes too!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks kind of questionable:

```
 if(temp->number == key)
    {
   found = 1;
    }
 temp = temp->next;   
 }
return found;
}
```

Why not just `return 1` as soon as `tmp->number == key` ? There's no reason to continue in the loop (or at least the rest of the code you pasted shows no reason) once a match is found.

The other thing is, I think you want to be testing `while (temp->next != NULL)` , instead of comparing an integer to NULL, especially before assigning `temp` to `temp->next`.

You'll also want to use something more along the lines of:

```
int keysearch (myStr *p, int key)
```

And have the caller responsible for passing the value to search.

Comment: oh sorry i corrected while ( temp->next !=NULL). And changed return in if and return 0 at the end. But where will I call this function in the append? That is questionable.

Comment: @DesperateCoders - I don't quite understand what you are trying to ask? If this is homework, post the full instructions of the assignment and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: I'm trying to control if added element is already exist in the linked list. I wanna do it before or while adding an element.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "its wrong"?

Beside that:

First. temp->number is an integer and you might want to check for the next pointer in your while statement.

Second. if you assign temp = p and key the value of p->number than youre check in the while loop will always be true for the first iteration.

Third. It might cause a crash if temp is not valid in your while statement.